# How to combine two strings to describe a property of tree.insert?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I'm creating a gui with tKinter, working with python for the first time.
Part of my gui is a treeview, the nodes in the treeview have images attached.
I made a function to add new nodes to the treeview.
I want to add an image to the new node based on the mother of the node.
In this case The variable 'curItem' returns the mother as a string, "test" in this case.
I want to combine the string "photo_" and "test" and use this in the 'tree.insert' code.
But for this to work I have to convert the string to something else, but I dont know to what and how to do this.

This is probably a very basic question, but I have been unable to find an answer so far.
Part of the relevant code:

```
photo_test = PhotoImage(file="resources/test.png")

def add():
    curItem = tree.selection()[0]    #returns "test"
    img = "photo_" + curItem
    tree.insert(curItem, 'end', text='new', image=img)    #doesn't work
    tree.insert(curItem, 'end', text='new', image=photo_test)    #works
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set the image to the string 'photo_test'. Try storing the actual photo in a dict and access it via the string, something like this.

```
photos = dict()
photos["photo_test"] = PhotoImage(file="resources/test.png")

def add():
    curItem = tree.selection()[0]    #returns "test"
    img = "photo_" + curItem
    tree.insert(curItem, 'end', text='new', image=photos[img])
```

You seems to have misunderstood the difference between a variable and a string though. A string is just text within the code, not actually code, so you can't pass a variable name in string form and expect the code to read that value. `"photo_test"` is not the same as `photo_test`.